# Access JSON file in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I want to access json file in angular.js by using the following code but I am unable to access the code because of the below mentioned shown error.
Help would be appreciated.!!

module :

```
angular.module("demoApp", ['demoApp.factory','demoApp.controllers']);
```

Factory:

```
angular.module('demoApp.factory', []).
factory('getJsonDataFactory',function($http){
    return{
    getData : function() {
        return $http.get('mapData.json');
    }
 }
});
```

controller :

```
angular.module('demoApp.controllers', []).
  controller('GetJsonController', function($scope,$http,getJsonDataFactory) {
              $scope.markers = [];  
              getJsonDataFactory.getData().success(function(data){
                $scope.photos=data;
            });
        });
```

Error :
In firefox:

```
 "Access to restricted URI denied" code: "1012"


return logFn.apply(console, args)
```

In Chrome :`

```
Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Comment: is it running on a server ?

Comment: What happen when just accessing the file via browser?

Comment: no.. this is not running on a server

Comment: Then need to change allow-file-access-from-files(chrome)

Comment: vittore - when access through browser , i am getting these errors shown up

Comment: Gopesh - ok .. what about firefox error?

Comment: check this link http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/ to enable file access in chrome

Comment: @Gopesh , thanks but i want to run it on firefox . and i am not able to identify this error

Comment: my problem has solved :) actually my firefox not updated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fact i think you don't have a server.

So, you're getting your application through the `file://` protocol.

But `file://` protocol **can't do http get methods for security reasons**.

To solve your matter i suggest you to put your application on a simple web server (like Apache, or wamp, xamp, lamp etc) or better to use grunt to build your application and run it on a test server through node.js

Comment: good catch. this question has nothing to do with angular or json